# How to remove duplicate emails in fetchmail?

Tags: gmail, fetchmail

I have the following situation: gmail polls my university email via pop3,
but it does so with a delay(around an hour sometimes). 
So I set up fetchmail to poll my university email.

It solves the delay issue, but since fetchmail polls gmail as well, so there's two copies of each mail sent to my university address(one from uni, other from gmail(that got it from uni)).
Is there a way for fetchmail to recognize duplicate emails and discard them?

Comment: In my experience, POP is rather unreliable (icluding duplicate mails, as you see). If IMAP is available, use that.

Answer (score 0):

But why don't you disable gmail pop3 ? Your job is done with fetchmail so there is no need to have both pop your mail from Uni.

I don't think fetchmail can recognize duplicate mail before it lands in your inbox. But you can delete the duplicates fast doing [this](http://kremvax.net/howto/mail-duplicates.html)

Comment: I don't disable gmail pop3, because I want to have all email in gmail, so that no mail is lost. Also for phone access.

Comment: I searched i bit around internet and there is no way fetchmail can recognize duplicates before they land in your inbox.